# Using tensorflow command in keras

Tags: python-2.7, keras

Is it possible in keras to use tensorflow tensor manipulations commands for altering the shape of data, of split by an axis or somethign like that..

I am currently trying something like this:

```
def row_convolution(input):
    filter_size = 8
    temp_list = []

    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,33,1,8,45,3))
    for section in tf.unstack(input,axis=1):
        section = tf.reshape(section,[1,8,45,3])
        temp_list.append((Conv2D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (8,45), activation='relu' , name = 'conv')(section)))
    print "len: " +  str(len(temp_list))

    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(temp_list))
```

Which is is the function for a lamdba layer, but the last command give me an error message stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator.py", line 182, in <module>
    fws()
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator.py", line 167, in fws
    model.add(Lambda(row_convolution,input_shape = (33,1,8,45,3)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 422, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 554, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 659, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator.py", line 147, in row_convolution
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(temp_list))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 637, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 702, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 110, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 99, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 451, in make_tensor_proto
    append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 109, in SlowAppendObjectArrayToTensorProto
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/conv/Relu:0' shape=(1, 1, 1, 1) dtype=float32>
```